# ¿Se pueden crear en tkinter un label y un entry (sin límite) cada vez que se pulse un botón y que cada uno se asocie automáticamente a una variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, variables

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para torneos tipo liga con cualquier número de participantes. De modo que al pulsar un botón se crea una label y un entry para introducir el nombre del nuevo participante. Como es número indefinido, no puedo asignar una variable a cada uno y me cuesta hacer después el resto de operaciones.

Y aquí la pregunta se divide en dos, ya que por un lado lo estoy tratando de solucionar agregando los nuevos participantes a una lista. Y hay varios problemas, el primero es que una vez introducido un nombre y pulsado el botón para introducir el siguiente, ya no puede corregirse ninguno de los nombres anteriores en caso de desear hacerlo porque queda metido en la lista y solo se lee el último entry. La solución que se me ocurre es que el entry de cada participante esté asociado a una variable generada automáticamente, pero no sé si eso puede hacerse.

En caso de que la solución fuera otra sin necesidad de asignar una variable a cada entry, me gustaría de todas formas saber si puede hacerse lo de crear variables para cada uno de los entries automáticamente al crearse los propios entries, ya que no encuentro esa opción por ningún sitio y me parece muy útil.

Añado el código de lo que llevo:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
raiz.title ("Torneo de 5")

raiz.config (bg="blue")
raiz.geometry("1000x800")

frame=Frame(raiz)

frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=4)


participantes=Frame(frame)
participantes.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=20, pady=20)

participantes.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
participantes.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

participantestitulo=Label(participantes, background="lightblue", text="Participantes", font= ("",15))
participantestitulo.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", columnspan=2)


list1=[]
num=len(list1)

listaparticipantes =[]
print (listaparticipantes)

a=0

def listarparticipante():
    
    if a==0:
        pass
    else:
        Participante=entry.get()
        listaparticipantes.append(Participante) 
        print(listaparticipantes)

def introducirparticipante (num):
    global entry
    global a
    list1.append(num+1)
    num=len(list1)
    label=Label(participantes, background="red", text="Participante "+str(num), font= ("",13))
    label.grid(row=num+1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    entry= Entry (participantes, justify="center", font= ("",13))   
    entry.grid (row=num+1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
    a=1


cuadrobotones=Frame(frame)
cuadrobotones.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=15, pady=15, columnspan=2)

cuadrobotones.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
cuadrobotones.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
cuadrobotones.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

botonsortear=Button(cuadrobotones, background="grey", text="Introducir participante", command = lambda: [listarparticipante(), introducirparticipante(num)], font= ("",16))
botonsortear.grid (row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=5,pady=5)
botonpillar=Button(cuadrobotones, command = lambda: listarparticipante(), background="grey", text="Terminar", font= ("",16))
botonpillar.grid (row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=5,pady=5)


raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola! Agregué la etiqueta Python a tu pregunta, ya que esta tiene relación con dicho lenguaje.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en Tkinter se utiliza el StringVar() para almacenar el valor de los Entrys, como es tu caso, y con tu ejemplo lo que más te conviene es crear una lista, donde cada vez que añadas un Entry, añades ese StringVar a la lista, y lo enlazas con el nuevo Entry que has creado, por lo tanto puedes consultar/modificar esa lista con el valor del StringVar.

El StringVar almacena el valor que en ese mismo momento tiene el elemento con el que lo has enlazado, por lo tanto si quieres obtener o modificar el valor de un elemento de Tkinter, se aconseja que lo hagas enlazándole ese tipo de objetos. Si el valor que estás almacenando es String, debes utilizar StringVar, si es un Boolean, pues deberías utilizar BooleanVar, como por ejemplo para el elemento de Tkinter Checkbutton.

Por lo tanto en tu caso lo primero que debes hacer es crear la lista de valores:

```
valores_jugadores = []
```

Despues en el metodo 'introducirparticipante(num):' añades a la lista el StringVar, y lo enlazas al Entry:

```
valores_jugadores.append(StringVar())
entry = Entry(participantes, justify="center", font=("", 13), textvariable=valores_jugadores[-1])
```

Y por último, para obtener todos los valores de todos los Entrys, en el método de listar_participante(): , podrías hacerlo así:

```
for i in valores_jugadores:
    print(i.get())
```

De esta forma obtienes los valores de los Entrys ya actualizados.

Te recomiendo también que utilices PEP 8, para tu código: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

El código completo funcional es este:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
raiz.title("Torneo de 5")
raiz.config(bg="blue")
raiz.geometry("1000x800")
frame = Frame(raiz)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=4)
participantes = Frame(frame)
participantes.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=20, pady=20)
participantes.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
participantes.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
participantestitulo = Label(participantes, background="lightblue", text="Participantes", font=("", 15))
participantestitulo.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", columnspan=2)

list1 = []
num = len(list1)

listaparticipantes = []

a = 0

valores_jugadores = []


def listarparticipante():
    if a == 0:
        pass
    else:
        '''
        Participante = entry.get()
        listaparticipantes.append(Participante)
        print(listaparticipantes)
        '''
        for i in valores_jugadores:
            print(i.get())


def introducirparticipante(num):
    global entry
    global a
    list1.append(num + 1)
    valores_jugadores.append(StringVar())
    num = len(list1)
    label = Label(participantes, background="red", text="Participante " + str(num), font=("", 13))
    label.grid(row=num + 1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    entry = Entry(participantes, justify="center", font=("", 13), textvariable=valores_jugadores[-1])
    entry.grid(row=num + 1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
    a = 1


cuadrobotones = Frame(frame)
cuadrobotones.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=15, pady=15, columnspan=2)

cuadrobotones.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
cuadrobotones.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
cuadrobotones.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

botonsortear = Button(cuadrobotones, background="grey", text="Introducir participante",
                      command=lambda: [listarparticipante(), introducirparticipante(num)], font=("", 16))
botonsortear.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)
botonpillar = Button(cuadrobotones, command=lambda: listarparticipante(), background="grey", text="Terminar",
                     font=("", 16))
botonpillar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)

raiz.mainloop()
```